# How to open shared Excel workbook larger than 5MB?

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-transfer, office365, onedrive

I was sent a link to a shared Excel file on OneDrive. When I click it, OneDrive says:

> Sorry, we can't open your workbook in Excel Online because it exceeds the 5 MB file size limit.

All I get is a mostly-blank window with no clickable elements.

Is there a way to download the file, or open it in some other system?

Comment: Download the file to your Desktop then open the file using Excel.  Due to the size you will be unable to use Excel Online to open the file

Comment: Yes, I'm asking HOW to download the file to my desktop. The link that I have only goes to a blank page.

Comment: If the file was shared with your account, then shared files should appear within OneDrive, by going to your OneDrive account within a browser.   How you download a OneDrive file that has been shared is beyond the scope of this particular Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 0):

@Ramhound's comment alludes to the relevant answer:

**If you log in to live.com first, then the size limit dialog box has an additional button: Open in Desktop App**, which will attempt to open the file in Excel on your device. You may also be asked to confirm your account so the shared file will become available in your own OneDrive. If you don't have Excel, accessing the file in OneDrive allows you to download it.

Unauthenticated users do not receive the desktop option and are shown a blank screen instead.